# Run command in background in oneliner

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, background-process

I'm not sure what these types of statements are called, but essentially I'm trying to do this:

```
[ "string" = "somethingelse" ] && dofuncwhentrue "param" || dofuncwhenfalse "param" &
```

So either function should be run in the background, but I'm not sure where to place the & to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't compromise readability to achieve one-liners!

Comment: @Inian I prefer reading this over an if statement or a case in bash, reduces the indentation. But if there's no alternative I'll suffer the spaces.

Comment: Notice that `<a> && <b> || <c>` is not 100% equivalent to `if <a>; then <b>; else <c> fi`: if `<b>` has a non-zero exit status, `<c>` will be executed as well in the first case, but not in the second. See the discussion in the [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Grouping_Statements).

Comment: @BenjaminW. good catch! I can still use the answer, but this should definitely be noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try trivial versions of your one-liner, you'll see the behaviour.

```
/bin/true && sleep 10 || sleep 10 &
/bin/false && sleep 10 || sleep 10 &
sleep 10 && sleep 10 || sleep 10 &
```

In all cases you'll see that `bash` spawns everything, including the test, into the background immediately.

If you really want the test to run in the foreground, you can structure the line with parentheses.

```
sleep 10 && (sleep 10 &) || (sleep 10 &)
```

As Inian has pointed out in a comment, using `if` would be more readable, but this is an interesting question!

Comment: Thanks for adding having the test in the foreground! Exactly what I was looking for.